# What's the difference between these SQL conditions?

Tags: sql, firebird

```
Select * from Example
where
1 = Case when :index = 0 then
         Case when DateEx Between :pDat1 and :pDate2 then 1 end
    else
         Case When :index = 1 or :index = 2 then
              Case When DateEx >= :pDat1 then 1 end
         end
    end
```

And

```
Select * from Example
where 
1 = Case when :index = 0 then
            Case when DateEx Between :pDat1 and :pDat2 then 1 end
    else 1
    end
and 1 = Case When :index = 1 or :index = 2 then
             Case When DateEx >= :pDat1 then 1 end
        end
```

Comment: I removed my answer since I misread the case statements.  The first of these is clearer in its intent.  And, very importantly, the first works with only the "between" case.  The second does not work in this case.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `BETWEEN` (pretty much ever, but especially with dates).  There are difficulties/weird corner cases involved, especially if you ever deal with timestamps.  It's much better to use a 'lower-bound inclusive, upper-bound exclusive' mentality (ie, `DateEx >= :pDat1 AND DateEx < pDat2`, where `pDat2` had been adjusted/calculated appropriately).

Comment: X-Zero, I really disagree with your sugestion of never using "between". It is perfect if you understand how it works. Also, no problem with DATE type. TIMESTAMP can be "tricky" in any conditionals.

Comment: @WarmBooter - If he can't tell the difference between these two statements its safe to say he doesn't know what `Between` does either.

Comment: In your first example only one of two When statements must pass. In the second example BOTH of the When statements must pass. One has an AND the other doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

The first example implements an OR condition.

It is true for the following cases...
A). `(:index = 0)               AND (DateEx Between :pDat1 and :pDate2)`
B). `(:index = 1 or :index = 2) AND (DateEx >= :pDat1)`

It's `A OR B`.

The second is less obvious.

It has two parts, seperated by `AND`.  But it has an extra `ELSE` in what would be `A` in the first version.

It's true if BOTH of the following are true...
A) `((:index = 0) AND (DateEx Between :pDat1 and :pDat2))  OR  (:index <> 0)`
B) `((:index = 1 or :index = 2) AND (DateEx >= :pDat1)`

But that's slightly broken.  Because if `:index = 0`, then `B` can *never* be true.

In fact, you don't need any `CASE` statements at all, just use this...

```
WHERE
  ((:index = 0)               AND (DateEx Between :pDat1 and :pDate2))
  OR
  ((:index = 1 or :index = 2) AND (DateEx >= :pDat1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite the first condition:

```
(:index = 0 AND DateEx BETWEEN :pDat1 AND :pDat2) 
OR 
(:index IN (1, 2) AND DateEx >= :pDat1)
```

The second condition can be rewritten:

```
(:index <> 0 OR DateEx BETWEEN :pDat1 AND :pDat2) 
AND
(:index IN (1, 2) AND DateEx >= :pDat1)
```

It is obvious that the second condition can be reduced to:

```
:index IN (1, 2) AND DateEx >= :pDat1
```

So, the difference is that first query deals with situation when :index = 0 and the second works only for :index = 1 OR :index = 2.